# Result from CTE query not sorted by Level, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Update:
I asked the question because the result does not look like how it is executed... which is explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Well I have another question...
If I do not need the same parents and the Level, is it possible to return one parent only once using the CTE (not the select after it) or maybe some other sql?

===========================
Desired result is like:

```
......
    54          4           
    **** the above is anchor member, the numbers are correct  
    4           1          
    1           0           
    2           1           
    36          35          
    35          8           
    8           1           
    54          12          
    12          1           
    11          1           
    3           1
```

===========================

I am using a recursive query to find out all the parents from a Hierarchy table, for items from Items table; I thought the result should be by Level, but it is not... I know I can sort it using order by, I just think the output itself should be ordered by Level because the Recursive Memeber is run by Level, right?

```
            WITH Result(ItemID, ParentID, Level)
            AS
            (
                --get the anchor member from tbItems
                SELECT itemID, itemParentID, 0 AS Level
                FROM   tbItems  WHERE
                    approved = 0 
                UNION ALL
                --recursive member from tbHierarchy
                SELECT h.hierarchyItemID, h.parentItemID, Level + 1
                FROM tbHierarchy AS h
                INNER JOIN
                    Result AS r
                        ON
                        h.hierarchyItemID = r.ParentID          

            )
            SELECT *
            FROM Result
```

the Result is:

```
    ItemID      ParentID    Level
    ----------- ----------- -----------
    7           3           0
    11          2           0
    18          11          0
    19          11          0
    21          54          0
    31          2           0
    33          36          0
    34          36          0
    35          36          0
    36          36          0
    38          2           0
    39          2           0
    40          2           0
    54          4           0
    **** the above is anchor member, the numbers are correct  
    4           1           1
    1           0           2
    2           1           1
    1           0           2
    2           1           1
    1           0           2
    2           1           1
    1           0           2
    36          35          1
    35          8           2
    8           1           3
    1           0           4
    36          35          1
    35          8           2
    8           1           3
    1           0           4
    36          35          1
    35          8           2
    8           1           3
    1           0           4
    36          35          1
    35          8           2
    8           1           3
    1           0           4
    2           1           1
    1           0           2
    54          12          1
    12          1           2
    1           0           3
    11          1           1
    1           0           2
    11          1           1
    1           0           2
    2           1           1
    1           0           2
    3           1           1
    1           0           2
```

Comment: You have no order by on the outer query. This means SQL Server is free to return the results in whatever order it deems most efficient. If you explain how you expect the results to be ordered, we can show you how to amend the query with a proper order by.

Comment: There is never a guaranteed order on how the rows are returned without an explicit `ORDER BY`, ever

Comment: hmm... why -1? this question should not be raised??? this is the first time i use the CTE, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in a database are not ordered. If you do not put an `order by`, you cannot be sure of the order of the output.

Never think the database will do things the way you think, 90% of the time, it's wrong. The objective of database is to understand your query and find the fastest way to find the solution, and it's often not the way you think.

Depending of your editor, but sometimes you can ask it to explain the plan used to find the solution, it might give you some explanation of how the result is obtained.

Comment: ok. if i want to return a parent only once, i need to use order by? is this the right way?

Comment: @shrimprice What do you mean "return a parent only once"? As I asked before, can you *please* post desired results as part of your question?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` will only affect the order of the result. You can use `WHERE` (in the recursive part) if you want to filter the results or a `GROUP BY` (in the outer select) to eliminate doubles.